# Session timeout issue in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I used this config in `web.config` file but the application logout sometimes in 20 seconds, sometimes in 5 minutes.

My config:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="40"></sessionState>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the IIS worker process idle timeout value (Default: 20 minutes)

You can change it at **IIS Manager > Application Pools > DefaultAppPool > Properties > Performance.**

Answer (score 0):

in IIS you can set idle timeout in minutes.there you can specify it. in `Application pools->choose your project->Advanced Settings->idle time_out(minutes)` you can set it here

Answer (score 0):

There may have issue with application pool recycle. you may need to set machine key in web.config. You can generate machine key from [here](https://www.allkeysgenerator.com/Random/ASP-Net-MachineKey-Generator.aspx)

```
<machineKey validationKey="44C0D499FB3076EACAC4F152325E806D269DDA2A63409AED8967FE2F4C0C5EAD22DEDFBC1AF7009FFD7C2BDE99765BB9483195D3B7C31515512B630400C0B735" decryptionKey="BBC3FB80FA576AE800CED1AAA9089699524A1EF83AD9A6372B72CB6894C326AE" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```